# OAuth "Pass Though" Authentication with Azure B2C

Tags: azure, authentication, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I have an application that uses Azure B2C.

If the starting point for a user is my application, it's easy to add an external identity provider, such as [Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-facebook) or [Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google).

It would follow the standard OAuth flow of:

1. Go to my site
2. Click login
3. Get redirected to B2C
4. Click the Facebook button and log in
5. B2C returns authenticated user details to my site.

However, I now have the situation where my site is not the starting point.

The flow is:

1. User is logged in at 'Company A'
2. User clicks a button to go to my site
3. An authentication step occurs automatically
4. User is now authenticated on my site.

If I were in charge of Authentication (using [ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity), for example), 'Company A' could call an API on my site with a single use code, I could send back the token. Then when the user was redirected, I could get that token back from 'Company A'.

However, not being in charge of the auth step, I'm having trouble.

I don't think we want to be using a [SAML flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs2016-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga) (different spec). The [SSO Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview) Overview doesn't seem to be of much help. There might be something in [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-get-started) that can do this, but I'm lost.

I think the doc I need might need is '[Pass an access token though a custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-custom)', but the fact they use Facebook in the example confuses me, as facebook wouldn't be calling Azure B2C, or Passing me anything about Facebook that I can use to send to B2C.

So, using Azure B2C, how can I get a user who is logged into another site to be logged in to my site automatically please?

Comment: Re-reading your question I'm not so sure now whether both you and 'Company A' are using B2C as the Identity Provider? Is that the case, or is it that 'Company A' has its own separate IdP and you need to pass a token through from that to B2C so B2C can read the information?

Comment: @DaveD - Company A have their own authentication system (currently unknown, but they are a very large corp, so Maybe Microsoft AD? could be on prem?). Appreciate any help! Thank you!